# How do I cancel an event after another one has started?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am having an issue, where after a Snackbar appears the FAB won't perform navigation for the period of the Snackbar message. If I click it multiple times when the Snackbar is displayed it will stack and open multiple instances of one screen (only after the Snackbar is gone). How do I cancel showing the Snackbar on click of the FAB and preserve the functionality of the FAB at all times?

TasksList.kt:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TasksListScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    viewModel: TaskListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val tasks = viewModel.tasks.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UiEvent.ShowSnackbar -> {
                    val result = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = event.message,
                        actionLabel = event.action,
                        duration = SnackbarDuration.Long,
                    )
                    if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnUndoDeleteTask)
                    }
                }
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> onNavigate(event)
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) { data ->
                Snackbar(
                    shape = RoundedShapes.medium,
                    actionColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                    snackbarData = data
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                shape = RoundedShapes.medium,
                onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnAddTask) },
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.fab_cd)
                )
            }
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(stringResource(R.string.app_name)) },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                )
            )
        },
    ) { padding ->
        LazyColumn(
            state = rememberLazyListState(),
            verticalArrangement = spacedBy(12.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 16.dp),
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        ) {

            items(items = tasks.value, key = { task -> task.hashCode() }) { task ->
                val currentTask by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = task)
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(confirmValueChange = {
                    if (it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnDeleteTask(currentTask))
                    }
                    true
                })
                SwipeToDismiss(state = dismissState,
                    directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
                    background = { },
                    dismissContent = {
                        TaskItem(
                            task = task, modifier = modifier
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TaskListViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TaskListViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TaskRepositoryImplementation) :
    ViewModel() {

    val tasks = repository.getTasks()

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    private var deletedTask: Task? = null

    fun onEvent(event: TaskListEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is TaskListEvent.OnAddTask -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TASK))
            }
            is TaskListEvent.OnEditClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TASK + "?taskId=${event.task.id}"))
            }
            is TaskListEvent.OnDeleteTask -> {
                val context = TaskApp.instance?.context
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    deletedTask = event.task
                    repository.deleteTask(event.task)
                    if (context != null) {
                        sendUiEvent(
                            UiEvent.ShowSnackbar(
                                message = context.getString(R.string.snackbar_deleted),
                                action = context.getString(R.string.snackbar_action)
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
            is TaskListEvent.OnUndoDeleteTask -> {
                deletedTask?.let { task ->
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        repository.addTask(task)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also share `onEvent()` from the viewmodel?

Comment: Here you are, edited

Comment: Hm... hard to tell what's the issue. Why do you need to launch a coroutine in `sendUiEvent()`?

Comment: If I try to change it says: `Suspend function 'send' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

Comment: I see, it's `Channel` that requires it. This probably has little to do with the actual issue, but I am wondering, would it make a difference to get rid of the `Channel` and  use instead a `StateFlow`? So basically: `private val _uiEvent = MutableStateFlow<UiEvent>(); val uiEvent: StateFlow<UiEvent> = _uiEvent`. And then just call `_uiEvent.send(event)` without launching a coroutine.

Comment: Nope, doesn't even let me compile with something like this. I don't think playing with channels is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this SnackbarController class to create a cancellable snackbar

Inspired by this repo [SnackbarController](https://github.com/mitchtabian/food2fork-compose/blob/d291d5114a0a5dd09e7d5ab2de3804607cfbd5d2/app/src/main/java/com/codingwithmitch/food2forkcompose/presentation/components/util/SnackbarController.kt)

Expose the method **cancelActiveJob** to cancel the visible snackbar

```
class SnackBarController(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
private var snackBarJob: Job? = null

init {
    cancelActiveJob()
}

    suspend fun showSnackBar(
    snackBarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    message: String,
    actionLabel: String? = null,
    duration: SnackbarDuration
): SnackbarResult {
    var result: SnackbarResult = SnackbarResult.Dismissed
    if (snackBarJob == null) {
        snackBarJob = coroutineScope.launch {
            result = snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = message,
                actionLabel = actionLabel,
                duration = duration
            )
            cancelActiveJob()
        }
    } else {
        cancelActiveJob()
        snackBarJob = coroutineScope.launch {
            result = snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = message,
                actionLabel = actionLabel,
                duration = duration
            )
            cancelActiveJob()
        }
    }
    snackBarJob?.join()
    return result
}

fun cancelActiveJob() {
    snackBarJob?.let { job ->
        job.cancel()
        snackBarJob = Job()
       }
    }
 }
```

In the TaskListScreen

```
val tasks = viewModel.tasks.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val snackBarController = SnackBarController(coroutineScope)
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    viewModel.uiEvent.collectLatest{ event ->
        when (event) {
            is UiEvent.ShowSnackbar -> {
                val result = snackBarController.showSnackBar(
                    message = event.message,
                    actionLabel = event.action,
                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Long,
                )
                if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                    viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnUndoDeleteTask)
                }
            }
            is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                //if you want to hide the snackBar
                snackBarController.cancelActiveJob()
                onNavigate(event)
            }
            else -> Unit
        }
    }
}
```

Note if you call snackbarController.showSnackbar() more than once
It replaces the current visible snackbar

Comment: It is giving me this error: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Unit' and 'SnackbarResult'"

Comment: I have edited the showSnackbar method to return a SnackBarResult. This can be used to check result == SnackbarResult.ActionPeformed in the TaskListScreen

Comment: Hmmm, now it is working as it was before adding the SnackBarController. Without recent changes and the if statement everything besides the undo was working.

Comment: Try now, i changed from the collect lambda to collectLatest and it works on my end

Comment: Not working for me